# Stripe, Failed to execute 'postMessage'

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to submit a form with a ibanElement, locally it works perfectly but on my test environment :  Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://js.stripe.com') does not match the recipient window's origin (https://my.test.com)

any suggestion?
Thanks for the help

```js
const ELEMENT_TYPE = 'card';

const PAYMENT_METHODS_CREDIT_CARD = "CREDIT_CARD";
const PAYMENT_METHODS_SEPA = "SEPA";

Vue.use(localeService);
const localeFromCookies = Vue.prototype.$getLocale(localeCookieName, null);

Vue.use(VeeValidate, { locale: localeFromCookies });

Vue.use(VueMask.VueMaskPlugin);

var paymentMethodsApp = new Vue({
    el: '#app-payment-methods',
    data() {
        return {
            wizardStepSize : 'md',

            paymentMethod : PAYMENT_METHODS_CREDIT_CARD,

            billingAddressStreet: null,
            billingAddressLine2: null,
            billingAddressCity: null,
            billingAddressPostalCode : null,
            billingAddressCountry: null,
            billingEmail: null,

            stripe: null,
            elements: null,
            cardElement: null,
            isCardElementEmptyOrInvalid : true,
            ibanElement : null,
            isIbanElementEmptyOrInvalid : true,

            paidCustomerId: null,
            paidSubscriptionId : null,
            stripeClientSecret : null,
            stripePaymentConfirmation: false,

            paymentMethodsSubmitting : false,
            billingDataChecking : true,

            alerts: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onCreditCardPaymentSelected() {
            Vue.nextTick(function () {
                paymentMethodsApp.mountStripeCardElement();
                paymentMethodsApp.unmountStripeSepaIbanElement();
            });
        },
        onInvoiceEBankingPaymentSelected() {
            Vue.nextTick(function () {
                paymentMethodsApp.unmountStripeCardElement();
                paymentMethodsApp.unmountStripeSepaIbanElement();
            });
        },
        onInvoicePhysicalPaymentSlipSelected() {
            Vue.nextTick(function () {
                paymentMethodsApp.unmountStripeCardElement();
                paymentMethodsApp.unmountStripeSepaIbanElement();
            });
        },
        onSEPAPaymentSelected(){
            Vue.nextTick(function () {
                paymentMethodsApp.unmountStripeCardElement();
                paymentMethodsApp.mountSepaElement();
            });
        },
        saveCustomer() {
            const customerData = {
                "paymentMethod" : this.paymentMethod,
                "billingAddressStreet" : this.billingAddressStreet,
                "billingAddressLine2" : this.billingAddressLine2,
                "billingAddressCity" : this.billingAddressCity,
                "billingAddressPostalCode" : this.billingAddressPostalCode,
                "billingAddressCountry" : this.billingAddressCountry,
                "billingEmail" : this.billingEmail,
            }

            return axios.post("/billings/customers", customerData)
                .then(response => {
                    this.paidCustomerId = response.data.paidCustomerId;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    if (error.response.status === 401 || error.response.status === 403) {
                        location.reload();
                    }

                    this.createAlert(saveBillingAddressErrorMsg);
                });
        },
        saveSubscription() {
            return axios.post("/billings/subscriptions")
                .then(response => {
                    this.paidSubscriptionId = response.data.paidSubscriptionId;
                    this.stripeClientSecret = response.data.clientSecret;
                    this.stripePaymentConfirmation = response.data.paymentConfirmation;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    if (error.response.status === 401 || error.response.status === 403) {
                        location.reload();
                    }

                    this.createAlert(saveBillingAddressErrorMsg);
                });

        },
        loadBillingDetails() {
            axios.get("/billings")
                .then(response => {
                    const responseData = response.data;
                    if(responseData) {
                        this.paidCustomerId = responseData.paidCustomerId;
                        this.paidSubscriptionId = responseData.paidSubscriptionId;

                        this.billingAddressStreet = responseData.billingAddressStreet;
                        this.billingAddressLine2 = responseData.billingAddressLine2;
                        this.billingAddressCity = responseData.billingAddressCity;
                        this.billingAddressPostalCode = responseData.billingAddressPostalCode;
                        this.billingAddressCountry = responseData.billingAddressCountry;
                        this.billingEmail = responseData.billingEmail;

                        if(responseData.paymentMethod) {
                            this.paymentMethod = responseData.paymentMethod;
                        }
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    if(error.response) {
                        if(error.response.status === 401 || error.response.status === 403) {
                            location.replace("/");
                        }
                    }
                })
                .then(()=> {
                    this.billingDataChecking = false;
                })
        },
        onProceedWithPaymentClicked() {
            this.$validator.validateAll()
                .then(isFormValid => {
                    if (isFormValid) {
                        this.doProceedWithPayment();
                    }
                });
        },
        async doProceedWithPayment() {
            this.paymentMethodsSubmitting = true;
            this.disableStripeCardElement(true);
            //this.disableStripeIbanElement(true);

            await this.saveCustomer();

            if(this.paidCustomerId) {

                await this.saveSubscription();

                if(this.paymentMethod === PAYMENT_METHODS_CREDIT_CARD) {
                    if (this.stripeClientSecret) {
                        if (this.stripePaymentConfirmation) {
                            await this.confirmCardPaymentWithStripe(this.stripeClientSecret);
                        } else {
                            await this.confirmCardSetupWithStripe(this.stripeClientSecret);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    location.replace("/watchers");
                }

                if(this.paymentMethod === PAYMENT_METHODS_SEPA) {
                    if (this.stripeClientSecret) {
                        if (this.stripePaymentConfirmation) {
                            await this.confirmSepaDebitPayment(this.stripeClientSecret);
                        } else {
                            await this.confirmSepaDebitSetup(this.stripeClientSecret);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    location.replace("/watchers");
                }
            }

            this.paymentMethodsSubmitting = false;
            this.disableStripeCardElement(false);
            this.disableStripeIbanElement(false);
        },
        confirmCardPaymentWithStripe(stripeCustomerClientSecret) {
            return this.stripe
                .confirmCardPayment(stripeCustomerClientSecret, {
                    payment_method: {
                        card: this.cardElement,
                        // billing_details: {
                        //     name: nameInput.value,
                        // },
                    }
                })
                .then((result) => {
                    if(result.error) {
                        this.$validator.errors.add({
                            field: 'creditCard',
                            msg: result.error.message
                        });
                    } else {
                        // Successful subscription payment
                        location.replace("/watchers"); //reload page and next step of activation wizard
                    }
                });
        },
        confirmCardSetupWithStripe(stripeCustomerClientSecret) {
            return this.stripe
                .confirmCardSetup(stripeCustomerClientSecret, {
                    payment_method: {
                        card: this.cardElement,
                        // billing_details: {
                        //     name: nameInput.value,
                        // },
                    }
                })
                .then((result) => {
                    if(result.error) {
                        this.$validator.errors.add({
                            field: 'creditCard',
                            msg: result.error.message
                        });
                    } else {
                        // Successful subscription payment
                        location.replace("/watchers"); //reload page and next step of activation wizard
                    }
                })
        },
        confirmSepaDebitSetup(stripeCustomerClientSecret) {
            return this.stripe
                .confirmSepaDebitSetup(stripeCustomerClientSecret, {
                    payment_method: {
                        sepa_debit: this.ibanElement,
                        billing_details: {
                            name: 'test',
                            email: this.billingEmail,
                        },
                    },
                })
                .then(function (result) {
                    // Handle result.error or result.setupIntent
                    location.replace("/watchers"); //reload page and next step of activation wizard
                })
        },
        confirmSepaDebitPayment(stripeCustomerClientSecret) {
            return this.stripe
                .confirmSepaDebitPayment(stripeCustomerClientSecret, {
                    payment_method: {
                        sepa_debit: this.ibanElement,
                        billing_details: {
                            name: 'test',
                            email: this.billingEmail,
                        },
                    },
                })
                .then(function (result) {
                    // Handle result.error or result.paymentIntent
                    location.replace("/watchers"); //reload page and next step of activation wizard

                })
        },
        initStripe() {
            this.stripe = Stripe(stripePublishableToken);
        },
        mountStripeCardElement() {
            this.paymentMethod = PAYMENT_METHODS_CREDIT_CARD
            const stripeOptions = {
                // stripeAccount: this.stripeAccount,
                // apiVersion: this.apiVersion,
                locale: localeFromCookies ? localeFromCookies : "auto"
            };

            const style = {
                invalid: {
                    color: "#a94442",
                    iconColor: "#a94442"
                }
            };

            const createOptions = {
                // classes: this.classes,
                style: style,
                // value: this.value,
                hidePostalCode: true
                // iconStyle: this.iconStyle,
                // hideIcon: this.hideIcon,
                // disabled: this.disabled,
            };

            this.elements = this.stripe.elements(stripeOptions);
            this.cardElement = this.elements.create(ELEMENT_TYPE, createOptions);
            this.cardElement.mount('#stripe-element-mount-point');

            this.cardElement.on('change', this.onStripeCardElementChange);
        },

        mountSepaElement() {
            this.paymentMethod = PAYMENT_METHODS_SEPA
            const stripeOptions = {
                // stripeAccount: this.stripeAccount,
                // apiVersion: this.apiVersion,
                locale: localeFromCookies ? localeFromCookies : "auto"
            };

            const style = {
                invalid: {
                    color: "#a94442",
                    iconColor: "#a94442"
                }
            };

            const createOptions = {
                // classes: this.classes,
                style: style,
                // value: this.value,
                supportedCountries : ['SEPA']
                //hidePostalCode: true
                // iconStyle: this.iconStyle,
                // hideIcon: this.hideIcon,
                // disabled: this.disabled
            };

            this.elements = this.stripe.elements(stripeOptions);
            this.ibanElement= this.elements.create('iban', createOptions);
            this.ibanElement.mount('#stripe-element-mount-point2');

            this.ibanElement.on('change', this.onStripeSepaElementChange);
        },


        unmountStripeCardElement() {
            this.$validator.errors.remove("creditCard");
            this.cardElement.unmount();
        },

        unmountStripeSepaIbanElement() {
            this.$validator.errors.remove("ibanSepa");
            this.ibanElement.unmount();
        },


        onStripeCardElementChange(event) {
            this.isCardElementEmptyOrInvalid = event.empty;
            if (event.error) {
                this.isCardElementEmptyOrInvalid = true;

                this.$validator.errors.add({
                    field: 'creditCard',
                    msg: event.error.message
                });
            } else {
                this.$validator.errors.remove("creditCard");
            }
        },



        onStripeSepaElementChange(event) {
            this.isIbanElementEmptyOrInvalid = event.empty;
            if (event.error) {
                this.isIbanElementEmptyOrInvalid = true;

                this.$validator.errors.add({
                    field: 'ibanSepa',
                    msg: event.error.message
                });
            } else {
                this.$validator.errors.remove("ibanSepa");
            }
        },

        disableStripeCardElement(disabled) {
            this.cardElement.update({disabled: disabled});
        },

        disableStripeIbanElement(disabled) {
            this.ibanElement.update({disabled: disabled});
        },
        setActiveTab () {
            const activeTab = this.$formWizard.attr("active-tab");
            if(activeTab) {
                const wizard = this.$refs.wizard;
                if(wizard) {
                    const currentActiveTabIndex = wizard.activeTabIndex;

                    wizard.changeTab(currentActiveTabIndex,activeTab);

                    wizard.tabs.forEach((tab, index)=>{
                        if(index < activeTab)
                            tab.checked = true
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        createAlert(message) {
            const alertItem = {
                key: new Date().getTime(),
                message: message,
                type: "danger"
            };

            this.alerts.push(alertItem);
        },
        onPageResize() {
            if (window.innerWidth > 992) { //media query value
                this.wizardStepSize = 'md'
            } else {
                this.wizardStepSize = 'xs'
            }
        }
    },
    computed: {
        $formWizard() {
            return $("#payment-methods-form-wizard");
        },
        disabledForm() {
            return this.paymentMethodsSubmitting
                || this.billingDataChecking
                || (this.paidCustomerId && this.paidSubscriptionId);
        },
        disabledPaymentMethod() {
            return this.paymentMethodsSubmitting
                || this.billingDataChecking;
        },
        disableSubmitButton() {
            return this.paymentMethodsSubmitting
                || this.billingDataChecking
                || (this.paymentMethod === PAYMENT_METHODS_CREDIT_CARD && this.isCardElementEmptyOrInvalid)
                || (this.paymentMethod === PAYMENT_METHODS_SEPA && this.isIbanElementEmptyOrInvalid)
                || this.errors.any();
        },
        showInvoiceEBankingPaymentMethod() {
            return wearerCountry !== 'CH';
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.setActiveTab();

        this.initStripe();
        this.mountStripeCardElement();

        this.loadBillingDetails();
    },
    created() {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.onPageResize)
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.onPageResize)
    }
});
```

```html
  <tab-content>
            <div>
            <div class="row" v-if="paymentMethod == PAYMENT_METHODS_CREDIT_CARD">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6 required" :class="{'has-error': errors.has('creditCard') }">
                        <label class="control-label">[[#{registration.payment.creditCard}]]</label>
                        <div class="form-control">
                            <form id="stripe-element-form" >
                                <div id="stripe-element-mount-point"></div>
                                <slot name="stripe-element-errors">
                                    <div id="stripe-element-errors" role="alert"></div>
                                </slot>
                                <button ref="submitButtonRef" type="submit" class="hide" ></button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <span v-if="errors.has('creditCard')" class="help-block">
                                {{ errors.first('creditCard') }}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
<div class="row" v-if="paymentMethod == PAYMENT_METHODS_SEPA">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6 required" :class="{'has-error': errors.has('ibanSepa') }">
                        <label class="control-label">[[#{registration.payment.sepa}]]</label>
                        <div class="form-control">
                            <form id="stripe-element-form" >
                                <div id="stripe-element-mount-point2"></div>
                                <slot name="stripe-element-errors">
                                    <div id="stripe-element-errors" role="alert"></div>
                                </slot>
                                <button ref="submitButtonRef" type="submit" class="hide" ></button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div id="mandate-acceptance">
                            By providing your payment information and confirming this payment, you
                            authorise (A) Smartwatcher Technologies AG and Stripe, our payment service provider
                            and/or PPRO, its local service provider, to send instructions to your
                            bank to debit your account and (B) your bank to debit your account in
                            accordance with those instructions. As part of your rights, you are
                            entitled to a refund from your bank under the terms and conditions of
                            your agreement with your bank. A refund must be claimed within 8 weeks
                            starting from the date on which your account was debited. Your rights
                            are explained in a statement that you can obtain from your bank. You
                            agree to receive notifications for future debits up to 2 days before
                            they occur.
                        </div>
                        <span v-if="errors.has('ibanSepa')" class="help-block">
                                {{ errors.first('ibanSepa') }}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </tab-content>
```

Comment: Could you share the code you're using?

Comment: yes sure.
What exactly you want to see?

Comment: The full code of the HTML/JS you've written.

Comment: Added, cardPayment works OK in all the enviroments, Sepa only locally, on test ->  Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://js.stripe.com') does not match the recipient window's origin (https://my.test.com)

Comment: Vanilla Stripe.js doesn't really work with Vue and has errors like this, you have to us third party wrappers like https://vuestripe.com/ instead.

Comment: ouhh, but not support (vuestripe.com ) for ibanElement?